# Keyboard lag/delay when using Gmail on Chrome only

Tags: windows, google-chrome, gmail

Recently, my computer has developed a lag when using gmail (typing in the search box or composing new messages) in Chrome. I don't have the same issue in Firefox on the same machine. I'm using a Dell Latitude E7440. My co-worker had the same exact problem (and he has the same computer). Other websites in Chrome do not have the same problem.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome (53.0.2785.116) on Windows 10 Enterprise.

I've tried using incognito mode, clearing my cache, disabling all extensions, and resetting Chrome, all to no avail. I use Microsoft Security Essentials for antivirus/anti-malware, and when I disabled it, I still had the problem. I've also tried disabling hardware acceleration and that had no effect.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.